# Citrix Load Testing Using jMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, citrix

Currently running some load testing using the Citrix Plugin for jMeter.

Currently facing issues with the 'Citrix Application Launcher'. This launches a user to an application login screen. A HASH check is in place to ensure that we are landing on the right page. We also use an OCR extractor to extract the value found on the screen (when in Blue screen that value = *** Warning ***

This step sometimes fails, as we can be met with a blue Windows screen detailing security policy and an okay button. Once the OK button is pressed, we land at the expected login page.

I need to modify my jMeter script to expect either of the pages pages -

1. Application Login
2. Blue Security Policy screen.

I have added an IF controller underneath Citrix Application Launcher with the following expression:
"${OCRValue}" == "*** Warning ***"

Within this IF controller there is a step which will then click the required OK button so we return to the expected login screen.

I can confirm the *** Warning *** value is being passed when entering into the BLUE screen, however the IF statement does not execute the Press OK step nested underneath.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E80L.png)

I expected that when entering the blue screen, the IF controller would execute the press okay, then we would return to the normal login screen.

However, instead, we are just held in the blue warning screen until the transaction times out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your If Controller condition is correct, the [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) will execute its children only when [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) resolves to `true`

I believe in your case you should wrap the condition into i.e. __jexl3() function like:

```
${__jexl3("${OCRValue}" == "*** Warning ***",)}
```

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)